# How to position camera behind player dependent on direction and lookat that direction in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera

I am creating a game with an autonomous camera. I want this camera to show where the player is moving towards. The game lets the player have a wide range of motion, its not just walking around in 3D. So for example if the player is falling down towards the ground the camera should position itself above the player, looking down onto it and the ground. And if the player is moving forward the camera should position itself behind the player, looking forward.

I have included what I think to be the best implementation of everything I've tried below, with comments explaining functionality and some of my issues.

```
///This should position the camera in a straight line between the player and the direction the player is heading. This seems to work to work nearly as expected, but seems to line up to what I believe to be the opposite direction in some cases.
v3T = player.transform.position - (player.GetComponent<Rigidbody().velocity - player.transform.position);
p2 = player.transform.position + v3T.normalized * 7.0f;
finalP = Vector3.SmoothDamp(finalP,p2,ref velocity, 0.002f, 850f);
transform.position = new Vector3(finalP.x, finalP.y, finalP.z);

//Using a LookAt like this leads for decent results, but not perfect. Possibly due to me not lining up the camera correctly?
transform.LookAt(player.transform.position);

//Using a Lookat in direction the player is moving doesn't give me the expected result. It seems to lose track of the player easily, and doesn't go in the direction that I thought it would at all times.
//transform.LookAt(player.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity)
```

[Camera not working correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2wQ7k.png)

[Camera working correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQA4K.png)

Comment: What do you mean by 'not perfect results'? What cases did you isolate where the camera is positioned in the opposite direction? If you could link an image of the scene with the camera and the character in one such case, that could help with checking the issue. As far as your commented LookAt() is concerned, the function should not work, since it takes a Transform object and you're passing it a Vector3 object.

Comment: I edited my original post with some pictures. It may be hard to tell exactly whats going on, but in the not working picture the camera is viewing the player from the side, not in a straight line between the player and the direction it is heading. This isn't opposite, but I have observed opposite in the past. In the camera working picture the player is falling down, the camera is above the player showing where the player is heading too. This is what I mean by not perfect results, I am unsure if this is from my LookAt or my camera positioning code.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I think I've kinda wrapped my head around this. There seems to be a clipping/intersection issue between the camera and the player which results in weird behaviour from the camera. I set up a small project, imported the 3rd person Standard Unity Controller and copied your code to the camera. At first I encountered the issue where the camera shows the player from the side. So then I added a static vector to the camera's starting position to correct the camera from overlapping with the Third Person Character and it fixed the issue (for me and my setup at least). Here is the Update function of the Camera component.

```
    ///This should position the camera in a straight line between the player and the direction the player is heading. This seems to work to work nearly as expected, but seems to line up to what I believe to be the opposite direction in some cases.
    v3T = player.transform.position + new Vector3(5,5,5); //- (player.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity - player.transform.position);
    p2 = player.transform.position + v3T.normalized * 7.0f;
    finalP = Vector3.SmoothDamp(finalP,p2,ref velocity, 0.002f, 850f);
    transform.position = new Vector3(finalP.x, finalP.y, finalP.z);

    //Using a LookAt like this leads for decent results, but not perfect. Possibly due to me not lining up the camera correctly?
    transform.LookAt(player.transform.position);

    //Using a Lookat in direction the player is moving doesn't give me the expected result. It seems to lose track of the player easily, and doesn't go in the direction that I thought it would at all times.
    //transform.LookAt(player.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity)
```

Here are some [screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ECqi.jpg) I took of my setup and of the camera's behaviour.

Comment: I really appreciate the help! I've actually done this in the past, but it created a couple of other issues. The camera can flip around quite quickly and disorientingly at times. I think this is due to passing over the static point? I also occasionally get side views still, although less often I think. https://imgur.com/a/9LTnt57
And Im not sure I completely sure why it would work. Wouldnt the cam position itself between the player and the static point? It wouldn't care of the if the player was heading down unless the static point was down?

Comment: I guess the static point you're talking about is my Vector above. In this case, the camera is positioning itself in a sphere around the player with radius equal to 5,always related to the player transform.I think that you manipulate somewhere in your code the player's rigidbody and that affects the physicality of the movement.Try to use the axis the player is looking at as a reference for LookAt,like [here](https://answers.unity.com/questions/308206/making-a-specific-axis-look-at-an-object.html),instead of the transform/rigidbody (since their values fluctuate in sudden cases, like falling)

Comment: I've been playing around with my code today. Putting it in FixedUpdate seems to make the camera focus on the static point like I described, while LateUpdate seems to act more as you described. I'm still trying to do the math in my head and understand why its working like this. Unfortunately I am in FixedUpdate due to using a rigid body and getting a jittery camera in LateUpdate. Sorry, but I'm a little confused by "Try to use the axis the player is looking at as reference". What do you mean exactly?

Comment: This is definitely weird behaviour, I would guess that you were using LateUpdate, but with Fixed, there shouldn't be such an issue. I'll do some more testing and check it out. Also, what I meant by the axis is that the camera would focus on the axis (or combination of two of those) that the player is looking to. So if the player is looking along the x axis, make the Camera look along that axis and simply follow the player. So, basically, this would be a simpler LookAt() but with less jitter due to fewer interpolations being performed.